# Storing Long/Lat in Sql Geography column or simpler column?

Tags: sql-server

This is the first time I have tried using the DbGeography type in my EF Code First design. 
My question is Should I be using simple float fields to hold the longitude and latitude of a location or should I be using the SQL type geography?

I'm beginning to think that geography is making things way more complex then they need to be.
I will be doing some area calculations based on the long/lat.

Comment: I have used float to store long / lat to find the nearest zip codes provided a zip code in search function

Comment: I too have struggled with geography.  I keep Lat/Lng in two separate fields.   It is easier for me especially when performing calculations and generating maps.

Comment: i know this can be programming focused, but i'd post on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you're going to make use of the [functions and other conveniences the Geography type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895266.aspx) I'd use the data type. Otherwise, float would be fine.